# Javascript scope - Need to preserve original value

Tags: javascript, scope

```
var oldArray = [],someArray=[],newArray=[];

oldArray = [4,5];
someArray =[1,2,3]; 
newArray = someArray;

for (var i=0; i<oldArray.length; i++){
    someArray.push(oldArray[i]);
}

// I want this to be [1,2,3] but it becomes [1,2,3,4,5]
// due to scope issue I believe
oldArray = newArray;
```

`newArray` needs to be original `someArray` of `[1,2,3]` when `oldArray = newArray`, however due to scoping by the time that `oldArray = newArray` it becomes  `[1,2,3,4,5]` instead.

How can I solve this issue? I need to preserve original `someArray` value and assign those values into `oldArray`.

Comment: This isn't a scope issue.

Comment: Matt, could you point to me a other posting that I can look if you think it's duplicate? I did some stackoverflow search and couldn't find the solution what I am having an issue.

Comment: Scroll up. It's at the top of your post now.

Comment: @whtflower if you want to create a real copy of an array, don't assign it, use `slice` instead: `var newArray = someArray.slice(0)`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7486130/4989460